# While expected, IF Statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

```
if (Mileage > 0) do
    {
        calculateMileage();
        cout << "The cost of shipment over " << setprecision(2) << Mileage << " miles is \234" << variableShippingCost << ".";
        cout << "\n \n";
        system("pause"); //to hold the output screen
        return(0);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n ERROR: The distance should be a positive value.";
        system("pause"); //to hold the output screen
        return(0);
    }
```

I have no clue why but *Visual Studio 12* is bringing an error on the else saying that it expects a while. I've done many *if else statements* before and also in this program that work fine so could anyone help me to understand why in this case it is not happy?

Comment: Who taught you to use `do` like that?

Comment: It's because of the `do` at the end of your first line. Either delete it, or add the `while` to go with it.

Comment: Oh lord, I feel like an idiot now! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: To append 0x499602D2's question: Who taught you to write `if(cond) do`, `return(0)` and `system("pause")`?

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is:

```
if (...) 
{...} else {...}
```

when using `if` and

```
do {...}
while (...);
```

when using `do...while`.

There's no `if() do` statement in C/C++!

Comment: Silly mistakes can happen to anyone, I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `do` after the `if`, so the compiler expects a `while` after the `do` block.

```
if (Mileage > 0)
{
    do
    {
        calculateMileage();
        //etc...
    } while (something);
}
else
{
    //etc...
}
```

or

```
if (Mileage > 0) // no `do` here
{
    calculateMileage();
    //etc...
}
else
{
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use do. that is for a while loop and the correct syntax for using that is

```
do{
...code here...
} while(some condition is true)
```

what you want is

```
if (Mileage > 0) //there is an implicit then here no need to do anything here
{
    calculateMileage();
    cout << "The cost of shipment over " << setprecision(2) << Mileage << " miles is \234" << variableShippingCost << ".";
    cout << "\n \n";
    system("pause"); //to hold the output screen
    return(0);
}   //<<<------if you really wanted to use the do (which you shouldnt) put a while here.
else
{
    cout << "\n ERROR: The distance should be a positive value.";
    system("pause"); //to hold the output screen
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing it wrong! C++ has if-else statements and do-while statements. `do` expects a `while` following itself, meanwhile `while` can be used independently.
Similarly, `if` can be used independently, but `else` expects an `if` before itself.